# multiple <data-tag="1"> possible ? Like <data-tag="1", "2", "3", "4">

Tags: php, jquery

I made a crafting filter for a game, and I wont to show visitors what recipe they miss when they have only 1 or 2 or 3 parts for a recipe.

http://daego.bplaced.net/filter.php

Example for a check-box :

```
  <div class="filterblock">
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="MetalBracket" class="category">
    <label for="check1">Metal Bracket</label>
  </div>
```

Result what he select :

```
  <div class="searchresults">
    <div class="resultblock" data-tag="MetalBracket">
      <div class="desc">
        <div class="desc_text">
        <a href = "http://daego.bplaced.net/Furnace.php"><b><i>Furnace</i></b></a><br>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

so what could i write to add more data-tags ?
Like this:

`data-tag="MetalBracket, ScrapMetal"`

Answer (score 2):

You can write it as a javascript array:

```
<div id="tags" data-tags='["javascript","jquery","css"]'></div>
```

and in your javascript:

```
var tags = $('#tags').data('tags');
console.log(tags);
$('#tags').append('<p>This works: ' + tags[0] + '</p>');
$('#tags').append('<p>This works: ' + tags[1] + '</p>');
$('#tags').append('<p>This works: ' + tags[2] + '</p>');
```

Your code working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ewv7o18k/2/)

Comment: sry i am not a professional in code writing, can u write me one example please ?

Comment: i seach again and i found perfect! example for my website, thx for your help !  http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/Ddnuh